# How to get every char from a text inside an element using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

*HTML

```
<div id="board_code" contenteditable="true">
    <div>a b</div>
    <div>cd</div>
</div>
```

*JS

```
var inlineDiv_num = $('#board_code > div ').size();
for( var x=0; x<inlineDiv_num; x++ ){
  var inlineDiv_num_textL = $('#board_code > div ').eq(x).text().length;
  for( var y=0; y<inlineDiv_num_textL; y++){    
        //PROBLEM HERE                  
        alert(  $('#board_code > div ').eq(x).eq(y).text() );
  }//for y
}//for x
```

I am expecting that the first alert will be 'a', 2nd is ' ', 3rd is 'c', 4th is 'd'. I will use the char that i get for comparison to something like intellisense thingy.

**NOTE**
My 2 for loop structure should not be compromised, i need this structure for latter solving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/uCaAW/) fiddle.

It will give all the characters one by one in the alert using the `substr` function.

**EDIT**: You can also use the `alert(inlineDiv_num_text.charAt(y));` function instead of `substr` as mentioned by ElisianoPetrini.

```
var inlineDiv_num = $('#board_code > div ').size();
for (var x = 0; x < inlineDiv_num; x++) {
    var inlineDiv_num_textL = $('#board_code > div ').eq(x).text().length;
    var inlineDiv_num_text = $('#board_code > div ').eq(x).text();
    for (var y = 0; y < inlineDiv_num_textL; y++) {          
        alert(inlineDiv_num_text.substr(y, 1)); //modified this
    } //for y
} //for x
```

Comment: wouldn't it be more convenient to use the charAt(y) method of the string object? (see my answer)

Comment: @ElisianoPetrini yep, but substring is the one that came to my mind first :D. I have updated the answer now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $ct = $('#board_code');

$ct.children('div').each(function(idx, div){
    var text = $(this).text();

    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        console.log(text.charAt(i))
    }    
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sn2gC/)

Comment: thanks but u should not eliminate the 2 loops structure on my code, i need those for latter use

Answer (score 0):

I'd structure it a bit differently.

```
$("#board_code > div").each( function(idx) {
    var s=$(this).text()
    for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        alert("'"+s.charAt(i)+"'")
    }
})
```

You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjzDf/